# Mod calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $$10x + 20  \equiv 11 \pmod{23}$$

So I know the answer is $6 \mod{23}$. I understand that we subtract $20$ from each side. But how do we do extended gcd on this?

Can you explain the steps involved?

Answer (score 5):

Below are a few ways to solve this modular linear equation. We use fractional modular arithmetic and we massage the fractions so that the quotient is exact, e.g. by pulling out factors and/or replacing $k$ by  $j\equiv k$ (colored the same below), for example $\ \color{#c00}{7\equiv 30\, \pmod{23}}$

$$\displaystyle\begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\ 23\!:\ \ 10x&\equiv&\, \color{blue}{14} &\,\Rightarrow\,& x&\equiv& \frac{14}{10}&\equiv& \,2\,\left(\dfrac{\color{#c00}7}{10}\right)&\!\equiv&\, 2\left(\frac{\color{#c00}{30}}{10}\right) &\!\equiv& 6\\
\\
\\
{\rm mod}\ 23\!:\ \ 10x&\equiv& \color{blue}{-9} &\,\Rightarrow\,& x&\equiv& \frac{-9}{10}&\equiv&\, 3\left(\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{-3}}{10}\right)&\!\equiv&\, 3\left(\frac{\color{#0a0}{20}}{10}\right) &\!\equiv& 6\\
\\
\\
{\rm mod}\ 23\!:\ \ 10x&\equiv& \color{blue}{-9} &\,\Rightarrow\,& x&\equiv& \frac{-9}{10}&\equiv&\ \ \, \dfrac{-18}{\color{#0a0}{\,\ 20}}&\!\equiv&\ \ \frac{-18}{\color{#0a0}{-3}} &\!\equiv& 6\end{eqnarray}$$

While this may seem a bit ad-hoc at first, it actually works surprisngly well for small numbers - often much more quickly than brute-force application of algorithms. For larger numbers it is generally best to employ an algorithm to compute inverses, such as the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841) for a worked example).

**Beware** $\, $ The above use of fractions in modular arithmetic is valid only when the denominator is a unit (invertible); else it is a zero-divisor so the quotient need not be unique, e.g. mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}$ cannot designate a unique solution. Indeed, the solution $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5\:$ requires cancelling $\,2\,$ from the modulus *too*, since $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\:$

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are units (invertibles). This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns in university algebra about the *universal properties* of fractions rings and localizations.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367841/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-modular-arithmetic-equations-such-as-9x-equiv-33/2368266#2368266) for much more on these & related methods / algorithms for computing modular fractions.

Answer (score 3):

$$10x+20 \equiv 11 \pmod{23} \implies 10x \equiv -9 \pmod{23} 10x \equiv -9+23 \pmod{23}$$
$$10x \equiv -9+23 \pmod{23} \implies 10x \equiv 14 \pmod{23} \implies 5x \equiv 7 \pmod{23}$$
$$5x \equiv 7 \pmod{23} \implies 5x \equiv 7+23 \pmod{23} \implies 5x \equiv 30 \pmod{23}$$
Hence,
$$x \equiv 6 \pmod{23}$$

Answer (score 1):

So, $10x\equiv -9 \pmod{23}$. Writing it on some other way, using e.g. $-9\equiv 14$, this is *even*, and $2$ is *coprime* to $23$, so *we can divide* the congruence by $2$:
$$10x\equiv 14\pmod{23} \ \implies \ 5x\equiv 7\pmod{23}$$
And the same trick again, use that $7\equiv 30\pmod{23}$, so what we have to solve can be also written as $5x\equiv 30\pmod{23}$ and now again we can divide by $5$ as it is coprime to the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *This may not be the most efficient way to solve this particular problem, but is a general method of solving linear congruences such as this.*

This is a linear congruence in the variable $x$. Using the definition of a modulus:

$$10x + 20  \equiv  11 \pmod{23}$$

$$\rightarrow 23|(10x + 20 - 11)$$

$$\rightarrow 23|(10x + 9)$$

$$\rightarrow 23y =10x + 9$$

$$\rightarrow 23y - 10x = 9$$

This is now in the form of a Diophantine equation: using the Euclidean algorithm, we can find the solution of:

$$23(-3) - 10(-7)= 1$$
$$23(-27) - 10(-63)=9$$

Meaning that $x=-63$ is one possible solution. We know that $63\equiv 6 \pmod{23}$.

Thus, $x=17$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be simpler to multiply by the inverse of 10 (mod 23), i.e., by $7$. Then you get $x$ alone and an easy calculation gives the result. It can be done in one line.