# What is the best way to solve modular arithmetic equations such as $9x \equiv 33 \pmod{43}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the best way to solve equations like the following:

$9x \equiv 33 \pmod{43}$

The only way I know would be to try all multiples of $43$ and $9$ and compare until I get $33$ for the remainder.

Is there a more efficient way ?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Divide both sides by $3$ and then multiply by $14$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you for your reply. Is there a more general definition for what you did? And what would be the solution? I know that the solution is $18$ but I don't see how you get that from what you wrote.

Comment: See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence

Comment: Find $n$ such that $9n\equiv A \pmod {43}$ with $|A|<9.$ E.g let $9n<43<9(n+1)$ or $9(n-1)<43<9n. $  In this case take $n=5.$ Then $9x\equiv 33\iff  2x\equiv 45x\equiv (5)(33)=165 \equiv 36.$....  We could repeat this method, e.g. $2x\equiv 36 \iff x\equiv 44x\equiv (22)(2x) \equiv (22)(36),$  but the "common -divisor" short cut can be used when available : Since $\gcd(2,43)=1$ we have $2x\equiv 36 \iff (2)(x)\equiv (2)(18) \iff x\equiv 18.$..... Or we can use the "short-cut" at the start: $9x\equiv 33 \iff 3x\equiv 11 \iff -x\equiv 42x =(14)(3x)\equiv (14)(11)=154\equiv -18.$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How would we solve it in $\mathbb{R}$?  Divide both sides by $9$ of course—or, in other words, multiply both sides by the multiplicative inverse of $9$.  This setting is no different.

The challenge is knowing the multiplicative inverse of $9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{43}$.  What is key$^\dagger$ is that $\gcd(9,43)=1$, which guarantees integers $n$ and $m$ such that $9n + 43m = 1$.  Modding out by $43$, we see that  $9n \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$.  Thus, multiplying both sides of $9x \equiv 33 \pmod{43}$ by $n$ gives us $x$.

The integers $n$ and $m$ can be found by using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

---

$^\dagger$ This [coprimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) condition is if-and-only-if.  An integer $x$ will not have a multiplicative inverse $(\text{mod} \ n)$ if $\gcd(x,n) \neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! We just realized our mistake :D Have a great day !

Comment: @ViktorG What was your mistake?

Comment: @BillDubuque we already calculated the multiplicative inverse of 9 and didn't think about multiplying both sides with it to make it simpler

Answer (score 4):

Generally the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) is an efficient algorithmic way to compute modular inverses & fractions, but often there are simpler ways for small or special numbers, e.g. below we give six ways to compute $\ x\equiv 33(9^{-1})=: \dfrac{33^{\phantom{|}}\!}9\equiv\dfrac{-10}9\pmod{\!43} =$  unique root of $\, 9x\equiv 33$

---

Cancel *invertible* factor $3$ then $\rm\color{#c00}{twiddle}\,$(add  $\,\pm 43j\,$  to make quotient *exact*, cf. [inverse reciprocity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

$$\dfrac{33}9\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{11}}3 \equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{54}}3\equiv 18$$

---

Factor the fraction then $\rm\color{#c00}{twiddle}$ the top

$$\dfrac{-10}9\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-2}}9\ \dfrac{5}1\equiv\dfrac{\color{#c00}{-45}}9\ \dfrac{5}1\equiv -5\cdot 5\equiv 18$$

---

[Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174676/solving-simple-congruences-by-hand/174687#174687)

$$\dfrac{-10}9\equiv \dfrac{-50}{45}\equiv\dfrac{-50}2\equiv -25\equiv 18$$

---

Extended Euclidean algorithm in *forward* equational form, then its associated [fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)

$$ \begin{array}{rr}
\bmod 43\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [\![1]\!]  &43\, x\,\equiv\ \ 0\    \\
[\![2]\!]  &\ \color{#c00}{9\,x\, \equiv -10}\!\!\!\\
[\![1]\!]-5\,[\![2]\!] \rightarrow [\![3]\!] &  \color{#0a0}{-2\,x\, \equiv\ \ 7}\   \\
[\![2]\!]+\color{orange}4\,[\![3]\!] \rightarrow [\![4]\!] & \color{#90f}{1\,x\, \equiv 18}\  
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\ $$

$$x\,\equiv\, \dfrac{0}{43}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\underbrace{\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-10}{9}}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\ \color{#0a0}{\dfrac{7}{-2}}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\
\color{#90f}{\dfrac{18}{1}}}
 _{\!\!\!\Large \begin{align}\color{#c00}{-10}\ \ + \ \ &\!\color{orange}4\,(\color{#0a0}{\ \, 7\ \, })  \ \ \equiv \ \  \color{#90f}{18}\\ 
                       \color{#c00}{9}\   \ +\ \   &\!\color{orange}4\,(\color{#0a0}{-2} ) \ \  \equiv\ \ \  \color{#90f}{1}\end{align}}\quad  $$

---

Fractional extension of the [binary extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#:%7E:text=The%20binary%20GCD%20algorithm%2C%20also,divisor%20of%20two%20nonnegative%20integers.), which uses only cancellation of $2$ and mediant subtraction $\ \frac{a}b\ominus \frac{c}d := \frac{a-c}{b-d}\pmod{\!43}$

$$\begin{align} 
&\dfrac{43}{43}\bmod \dfrac{33}9 \equiv \dfrac{15}8\ \left[\:\! {\rm by}\,\  \dfrac{43}{43}\ominus\dfrac{33}9 \equiv \dfrac{10}{34}\equiv \dfrac{5}{17};\ \ \dfrac{5}{17}\ominus \dfrac{33}9 \equiv\dfrac{15}8\right]\\[.6em]
&\dfrac{33}9 \bmod  \dfrac{15}8 \equiv\color{#90f}{\dfrac{18}1}\ \left[\:\! {\rm by}\,\  \dfrac{33}9\ominus  \dfrac{15}8\equiv \dfrac{18}1\right]
\end{align}$$

There is an analogous fractional "reverse" Euclidean algorithm for computing modular inverses and fractions for polynomials $\,f(x)\,$ over a field, using only cancellation of $x$ and (scaled) mediant addition / subtraction $\,\frac{f}g\:\!\oplus\:\! c\!\cdot \!\frac{f'}{g'} := \frac{f+cf'}{g+c\:\!g'},\,$ e.g. see [Joe Silverman's note](https://ntru.org/f/tr/tr014v1.pdf) and [this question on such](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989935/how-to-represent-xn-1-in-the-ring-mathbbz-3-mathbbzx-xn-1), where the modulus is $\,x^n-1\,$ so cancellation of $x = $ multiplication by $x^{-1}\equiv x^{n-1}\,$ is a trivial cyclic shift (analogous to the fact here that cancelling $2$ is trivial: if the numerator is odd then add or subtract the odd modulus to to get an even rep, then cancel $2$ from the even numerator and denominator, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242)). Note: JS's presentation does not use the above fractional or reverse / localized Euclidean viewpoint but instead uses essentially elementary row operations as in standard algorithms for computing Hermite / Smith normal forms.

---

We can also use Newton's method (Hensel lifting) to lift inverses to higher powers, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3540538/242).

---

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) for general theory and algorithms to solve a linear congruence $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}$

---

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) for a handful of methods applied to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{9}{x}\equiv\mathrm{33}\left({mod}\mathrm{43}\right)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
$\mathrm{3}{x}\equiv\mathrm{11}\left({mod}\mathrm{43}\right)\equiv\mathrm{54}\left({mod}\mathrm{43}\right) \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:{x}\equiv\mathrm{18}\left({mod}\mathrm{43}\right)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $

Comment: This is by far the best method of all the answers

Answer (score 0):

$43$ is prime.  And even if it weren't, $\gcd(9,43)= 1$.

That means we know that $9^{-1}_{43}$ exists.  That is there is a number so that $9\cdot 9^{-1}_{43} \equiv 1 \pmod {43}$.  And we *could* calculate  (or guess) that $9^{-1}_{43}\equiv 24$ (because $9\cdot 24\equiv 1 \pmod {43}$) and we can solve $9x \equiv 33\pmod {43} \implies 24\cdot 9 x\equiv x \equiv 24\cdot 33\pmod {43}$.

But we don't *have* to.  If $\gcd(9,43) =1$ and if $9^{-1}$ exists, then in this case we are allows to know that division is acceptable, and we are, in this case, allowed to divide both sides by $3$.

$9x \equiv 33 \pmod {43}$

$3x\equiv 11 \pmod {43}$  (we *wouldn't* be allowed to do this if $\gcd(3,43)\ne 1$)

Now $3$ is such a small number that we know that one these:  $11, 11 + 43, 11+2*43$ is divisible by $3$.

As it turns out $3x \equiv 11 \equiv 11 + 43 \equiv 54\pmod {43}$.

And we can divide both sides by $3$ to get

$x \equiv 18\pmod {43}$.[1]

..........

Alternatively we can do baby steps.

$9x \equiv 33 \pmod {43} \implies$ there is a $k$ so that

$9x = 33 + 43k$.  Divide by $3$ and we get

$3x = 11 + 43\frac k3$.  That will be an integer so long as we choose a $k$ that is divisible by $3$.  Relable $m= \frac k3$

$3x = 11 + 43m$

$3x =11 + 43 + 43(m-1)$

$3x = 54 +43(m-1)$

$x = 18 + 43\frac {m-1}3$ which is an integer so long as we select $m-1$ so that $m-1$ is divisible by $3$.  (For example the easiest example is $m-1=0$, $m=1$, $k = 3$ an $9*18 = 33 + 3\cdot 43$.  But we don't need to find the actually $k$)

......

[1] Notice our earlier answer $24\cdot 33\equiv 24\cdot 32 + 24\equiv 48\cdot 16 + 24 \equiv 5\cdot 16 + 24\equiv 80 + 24 \equiv 86 + 18 \equiv 18\pmod {43}$.  So our answers are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP observes,

$$9x \equiv 33 \pmod{43} \text{ iff } 9x - 33 = 43k$$

but this leaves us with a considerable amount of calculating as we start increasing $x$ from $2$ on up.

But by *modding out* by $9$  on the right side equation, we can eliminate the $x$ variable:

$$\tag 13 \equiv 7k \pmod{9}$$

So we can solve the starting problem if we can solve $\text{(1)}$, but this one can be done by inspection - we get $k = 3$ as the minimal positive integer choice for $k$, and thus

$$ 9x - 33 = 43 \times 3 \text{ iff } x = 18$$