# How to solve $ab\bmod c = d$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can $ab\bmod c = d$ be solved, if $b$, $c$ and $d$ are known?

A similar algorithm is used by LCGs (weak PRNG) to give random values.
To solve this, I used WolframAlpha which quickly solved, but shown nothing about process.

What is the process to solve such problems?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) for a handful of ways to solve $\ bx\equiv d\pmod{\!c}\ \ $

Comment: How can that be applied here? If I am not wrong, d mod c is constant.

Comment: The usual notation for this is
$$ab \equiv d \pmod c$$