# How to solve and get the general solution of a congruence equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm following the tutorial of an online calculator to solve congruence equations

I'm doing the same as they are doing but I never get the same result, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

the tutorial http://www.a-calculator.com/congruence/#faq-formula

$28x\equiv 14 \ $mod $6$

$28$ mod $6$ and $14$ mod $6$ I get

a = $4$ and b = $2$

the linear combination of the $gcd(4,6) =$ $4(-1) + (1)6 = 2$

putting into the formula I get

$\begin{equation*}
     x_0 = \frac{2(-1)}{2} \; ( \text{mod} \; 6)
    \end{equation*} = 5$

general solution
\begin{equation*}
     x_n = 5 + \frac{n(6)}{2} \; ( \text{mod} \; 6) 
    \end{equation*}

the final answer is

```
General form of solutions: 2 + 3k.

Solutions for x less than 6: 2,5.
```

Comment: You cannot generally use division with congruence equations.

Comment: you can convert congruences into algebra ( sometimes with multiple variables) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401795/solving-for-x-in-modular-equation/2401823#2401823 @ElliotG I disagree to some extent, you just have to be very careful. in this case you can reduce to $14x \equiv 7 \bmod 3$ which then converts down to $2x\equiv1\bmod 3$ which then can give you the result.

Comment: your answer is equivalent.  The set all numbers that can be represented as 5+3k is the same set as the set that can be represented 2+3k.  But rather than memorizing formulae, you should really be trying to understand the algebra.

Comment: @DougM You are right, but I don't have much time left to learn such a complex thing, but anyways, thanks.

Comment: @hjx it's as easy as 5+3x = 2+3(x+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can take all the coefficients down by congruence with the modulus.

$$28x\equiv 14 \bmod 6 \quad\to\quad 4x\equiv 2\bmod 6$$

Note that here, in concept, you are **not** dividing by $7$ - you are taking $28\bmod 6 $ and $14\bmod 6$ (even though the effect is the same).

Then you can put aside the common factor of $2$ from coefficients and modulus (although you may need to bring it back for the solution eventually):

$$4x\equiv 2 \bmod 6 \quad\to\quad 2x\equiv 1\bmod 3$$

Now, by examination, $x\equiv 2\bmod 3$ meaning - if you need to present the result $\bmod 6$ - $x\equiv \{2,5\} \bmod 6$, as per your text book.

Rather than a case where you can solve this last step "by examination" you may need to explicitly find the multiplicative inverse (and in this case that is what the equation amounts to anyway). For small moduli this may be an easy search; in general you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Since your arrows are unidirectional, your deductions are only *necessary* but not *sufficient* conditions on solutions. In fact the reverse directions hold too, but you need to explicitly state that if you want to deduce the candidates are actually solutions without having to verify that.

Comment: Why doesn't the given formula $\begin{equation*}
     x_0 = \frac{bp}{\text{gcd}(a, m)} \; ( \text{mod} \; m).
    \end{equation*}$ give the $x_0$ as 2 ?

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm indicating process rather than formal logical linkages with the arrows, which is why I drew them as single-stemmed. But apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @hjx your formula has $x_{-1}=2$, so that solution is available. You could have got $x_0=2$ by using $2\cdot4 +(-1)\cdot 6 = 2$ for the gcd linear combination

Comment: Thanks, Could you please explain this part ? Now, unless gcd(a,m) evenly divides b there won't be any solutions to the linear congruence. Though if it does, our first solution is given by

Comment: you can also get the $x\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ part from noting $4\equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and then then you have an equivalent to $2x\equiv 4 \bmod 3\to x\equiv 2 \bmod 3$

Answer (score 2):

$$28x\equiv 14\mod 6$$ means $$6|28x-14$$

Since $28x-14$ is even for every integer $x$, this is equivalent to $$3|28x-14$$ and therefore $$28x\equiv 14\mod 3$$

Reducing $28$ and $14$ mod $3$ gives $$x\equiv 2\mod 3$$

Hence the positive solutions are $2,5,8,\cdots$

Comment: Why doesn't the given formula $\begin{equation*}
     x_0 = \frac{bp}{\text{gcd}(a, m)} \; ( \text{mod} \; m).
    \end{equation*}$ give the $x_0$ as 2 ?

Comment: What does "p" mean in this formula ?

Comment: $\begin{equation*}
     ap + mq = \text{gcd}(a, m).
    \end{equation*}$

Comment: http://www.a-calculator.com/congruence/#faq-formula

Comment: @hjx so bezout's identity.

Answer (score 1):

There in no discrepancy: $ $ your solution is $\,x\equiv\, 5,\,5\!+\!3\,\equiv\, 5,\,2\pmod{\!6},\,$ same as claimed.

**Remark** $ $ Generally, as above, we will need to reduce the results of the formula $\bmod m\,$ if we wish to obtain the *least* nonnegative representatives of the solutions.

Comment: Bill, in the tutorial the writter says, Now, unless gcd(a,m) evenly divides b there won't be any solutions to the linear congruence. Though if it does, our first solution is given by.. Could you explain what did He meant by saing that ?

Comment: in the formula, what is this (mod m) taking mod of ?

$\begin{equation*}
     x_n = x_0 + \frac{nm}{\text{gcd}(a, m)} \; ( \text{mod} \; m) 
    \end{equation*}$

I solved the following congruence $131x\equiv 21 \ (mod \ 77)$ and I got

$ 56 + \frac{77n}{1}$ mod $77$, $77$ mod $77$ would be 0.

Comment: @hjx If $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\!m}\,$ is solvable then $\,b = \color{#c00}ax-\color{#c00}mn\,$ so $\,d\mid \color{#c00}{a,m}\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid b.\,$ Thus choosing $\,d = \gcd(a,m)\,$ we can cancel $\,d\,$ from $\,a,b,m\,$ so reducing to the simpler case where $\,a,m\,$ are coprime, so $\,a^{-1}\!\pmod{\!m}\,$ exists, so $\,x\equiv a^{-1}b\pmod{\!m}.\\ $

Comment: @hjx It's not "taking mod". Rather $\,x\equiv y\pmod{\!m}\iff m\mid x-y\iff x,y$ leave the same remainder when divided by $m,\,$ i.e. $\ x\bmod m\, =\, y\bmod m.\,$ For more  on "mod" as a binary operator (remainder) vs. ternary congruence relation see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) and [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121054/242)

Comment: Bill, that is a = not the $\equiv \ $,  $\begin{equation*}      x_n = x_0 + \frac{nm}{\text{gcd}(a, m)} \; ( \text{mod} \; m)      \end{equation*}$

Comment: @hjjx It should be $\,x_0\equiv\,\ldots $ not $\,x_0 =\,\ldots $ since the latter is not even defined. But there is much abuse of notation when it comes to congruences (and much misunderstanding).

Comment: Is there  other techniques to find the general solution of a congruence equation ?

Comment: @hjx That is the standard method for solving a linear congruence. There are various methods to solve the subproblem of computing $\, b/a\equiv a^{-1}b\pmod{\!m}.\ \ $