# There is no $m$ for that $1000^m-1 \mid 1978^m - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The following problem is taken from "All Soviet Union Math Competition 1978":

> Prove that there is no $m$ for that $(1000^m - 1) \mid (1978^m - 1)$

A direct solution is using [LTE lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma): $$\nu_3(1000^m-1) = \nu_3(1000-1) + \nu_3(m) = 3 + \nu_3(m)$$but $$\nu_3(1978^m-1) = \nu_3(1978-1) + \nu_3(m) = 1 + \nu_3(m)$$so $\nu_3(1978^m-1) < \nu_3(1000^m-1)$.

I still wonder if there is a simpler solution for this problem (since this is a problem for 8th grade pupils so LTE seems overkill, IMHO).

Comment: That looks like a simple solution. What exactly are you asking for? Are you hoping that it doesn't use such advanced machinery?

Comment: This is a problem for 8th grade pupils so LTE seems overkill, IMHO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose towards contradiction that there exists such an $m$, and write $$1978^m - 1 = 1978^m - 1000^m + 1000^m - 1.$$ Clearly $1000^m - 1$ is divisible by itself, so we only need to show that
$$1978^m - 1000^m = 2^m \cdot (989^m - 500^m)$$is divisible by $1000^m - 1$.
Now since $\mathrm{gcd}(2^m, 1000^m - 1) = 1$, we must have that
$$(1000^m - 1) \mid (989^m - 500^m).$$
But this doesn't hold, since for $m > 0$, $989^m - 500^m < 1000^m - 1$ (and this inequality is true because clearly $989^m + 1 < 1000^m + 500^m$). Contradiction.

Comment: I think it would be "the" solution. Thank you.

Comment: That's simple indeed :)

Comment: @CalvinLin Even more simply, it can be viewed as a special case of the binary Euclidean algorithm, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given said level, likely it was intended to use the [(binary, subtractive) Euclidean gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm). This computes gcds using the following reduction step $\,(A,B) = (A,B\!-\!A)\,$ if $\,B > A,\,$ then factor out any common factors of $\,2,\,$ leaving at most one $\rm\color{#0af}{even}$ argument, from which we cancel all factors of $\,2\,$ (valid by $\,2\nmid m\Rightarrow (m,\color{#0af}{2^k} n) = (m,n)\,$ by Euclid). For example

$$\begin{align} (48,176) &= (48,128)\ \ \text{by subtracting least from greatest}\\[.1em]
&= 16\:\!(3,\color{#0af}8)\ \ \ \ \text{by factoring out as many $2$'s as possible}\\[.1em]
&= 16(3,\color{#c00}1)\!=\!16,\ \text{by cancelling all $2$'s from $\,\color{#0af}8,\,$ leaving $\,\color{#c00}1$}
\end{align}\qquad$$

More complicated gcds require more than this single step, e.g. above instead of $(3,1)$ we may reach $(m,n)\,$ for odd $\,m,n>1\,$ so we need to inductively (recursively) apply the algorithm to compute that smaller gcd. The same idea works for any radix, e.g. for decimal we extract/cancel factors of $\,2\,$ *and* $\,5\,$ (easily recognizable from the units digit).

Like the above example, the OP  requires only a single step - which we perform in the proof below. To aid future use we do a slightly generalized problem, for base $\,e.\,$ Specializing the Lemma below yields essentially the same arithmetic as in the accepted answer (but we show how to *discover* it).

**Lemma** $ $ If $\,A =\color{#c00}a\:\!e^m\!+c,\,\ B = \color{#0a0}b\:\!e^m\!+c,\,\ (e,c)\!=\!1\,$ then $\,A\mid B\iff A\mid \color{#0a0}b\!-\!\color{#c00}a$

**Proof** $\,\ A\mid B\!\iff\! A \!=\! (A,B) \!=\! (A,B\!-\!A) \!=\! (A,(b\!-\!a)\color{#0af}{e^m}) = (A,b\!-\!a)$ $\!\iff\! A\mid\color{#0a0}b\!-\!\color{#c00}a\,$ where we cancelled $\,\color{#0af}{e^m}$ by Euclid, using $\:\!\color{0a0}e\:\!$ is coprime to $A$ by  $\,(A,e) = (c,e) = 1$. $\ \ \bf\small QED$

---

OP has $\:\!A = \color{#c00}{500^m}2^m-1,\ B = \color{#0a0}{989^m} 2^m-1\,$  so $\:\!A\mid \color{#0a0}b\!-\!\color{#c00}a\,$ fails here since $\,A > b\!-\!a>0\,$ (i.e. we have: $\,A\!=\!1000^m\!-\!1 > 989^m > \color{#0a0}{989^m}\!-\!\color{#c00}{500^m}\! = \color{#0a0}b\!-\!\color{#c00}a),\,$ thus $\,A\nmid B\,$ by the Lemma.

**Remark** $ $  The point of *explicitly* presenting it as a special case of one form of the Euclidean algorithm is that this ubiquitous method shows us how to *discover* the solution using general methods. We could instead eliminate all use of the algorithm and present the proof using only divisibility arithmetic - but that would obfuscate the idea that led to the  discovery of the proof.

It deserves to be better known that there is an analogous algorithm for polynomials, e.g. see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) where I explain how it can be used to understand a note by Joe Silverman on almost inverses.

Answer (score -3):

$$1000^\color{red}{n}-1=999\times(n \pmod 3)$$
$$1978^m-1=1977\times(m\pmod 3)$$
And $999$ does not divide $1977$.

Thinking modulo $3$, I think a desperate Russian student like Nu can conclude...